# calculate differences from subsets in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with 2 factors. like this

```
Eyecolour Haircolour Points
   <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>
1  brown blond         4
2  brown brunette      -8
3  blue  blond         2
4  blue  brunette      3
5  green blond         -5
6  green brunette      9
```

I would like to have the difference in Points between blond and brunette for every `Eyecolor` or just simply subtract blond from brunette for every `Eyecolor`.

I tried to use `dplyr` package but I am struggling to get the code right. Also with `diff()` doesnt like negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
Eyecolour Haircolour Points
brown blond         4
brown brunette      -8
blue  blond         2
blue  brunette      3
green blond         -5
green brunette      9"), header = T)
```

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::spread(Haircolour, Points) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(diff = blond - brunette)
```

**RESULT**

```
  Eyecolour blond brunette diff
1      blue     2        3   -1
2     brown     4       -8   12
3     green    -5        9  -14
```

Comment: Works great and easy! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(Haircolour = as.character(Haircolour)) %>% 
   group_by(Eyecolour) %>% 
   summarise(Diff = Points[Haircolour=="blond"] - Points[Haircolour =="brunette"])
#   Eyecolour  Diff 
#      <fctr> <int>
#1      blue    -1
#2     brown    12
#3     green   -14
```

---

Or using `data.table`,

```
 library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df), Eyecolour~Haircolour, value.var="Points")[, Diff:= blond-brunette][]
 #   Eyecolour blond brunette Diff
 #1:      blue     2        3   -1
 #2:     brown     4       -8   12
 #3:     green    -5        9  -14
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  Yes, when I got your reply that you are not working on it.